# What is the best way of setting CSS styles for :hover and .selected at the same time?

Tags: html, css

I have a navigation bar with multiple `<a>` links. Only one has the **selected** class at any given time:

```
<a href="#">Home</a>
<a href="#" class="selected">Preferences</a>
<a href="#">Log Out</a>
```

I'd like the `:hover` and `.selected` styles to look the same. Currently I'm using:

```
#navigation a.selected, #navigation a:hover {
    ...
}
```

Is there a simpler way of combining the two selectors, or is this the best way of doing it?

Comment: You are doing it the best way.

Comment: I guess it might be nice if you didn't have to repeat the "#navigation" part, but even though you do it is pretty simple as is.

Comment: It gets a lot worse when you're doing long selectors, like `#container .navigation li a img`. Sure, you could shorten it, but I like the more descriptive selectors because it makes it easier to find what you're selecting in the HTML.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no way to combine the same style for a class and the hover selector, your current approach is fine.